# Sending data between two phones using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

I added GAE to my app using [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) tutorial.

My question is, instead of sending the string to and from the same app on one phone, how would I go about sending it to the same app on another phone?

Comment: Instead of putting link, could you please put the part of tutorial in the question for which you are asking question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the most current way to send messages to a device from endpoints is [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) [GCM]. One device would initiate the message and send it to your App Engine backend then the backend would use GCM to send it to the target device.